# File sizes are reported differently

Tags: windows-10

Why are file sizes all different?

[image: File Sizes]

In Windows 10 I can see all of these sizes:

- `11,116 KB`
- `10.8 MB`
- `11,382,240 Bytes`
- `11,382,784 Bytes`

If I use the **Console Window**:

```
D:\My Programs\2017\MeetSchedAssist\Inno\Output>dir *.exe
 Volume in drive D is DATA
 Volume Serial Number is A8B0-A5C6

 Directory of D:\My Programs\2017\MeetSchedAssist\Inno\Output

03/04/2018  08:50        11,382,240 MeetSchedAssistSetup.exe
               1 File(s)     11,382,240 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  719,837,487,104 bytes free

D:\My Programs\2017\MeetSchedAssist\Inno\Output>
```

I understand that perhaps on the physical media it has to round it to physically take a certain amount of space, but that line above:

> Size:  10.8 MB (11,382,240 bytes)

Huh? Why does it not say `11.38 MB`?

Comment: 11382784 / 1024 = 11116 and 11116 / 1024 = 10.855

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once upon a time it has been defined that

> 1 kB = 1024 B
>
> 1 MB = 1024 kB

If you divide your bytes figure all the way down to MB, you'll get all those figures.

Now that they noticed that many people tend to walk into that trap, they have redefined the unit multiples and defined new ones

> 1 kiB = 1024 B
>
> 1 MiB = 1024 kiB
>
> 1 kB = 1000 B
>
> 1 MB = 1000 kB

but this scheme is not so widespread (seems to be more common with total size specs of storage media).

**Funny sidenote:** I guess I am not the only one who has learned it the old way and now mixes it up with the current definition all the time. I'd say problems like this are the root cause for humanity being mostly conservatively oriented.